# is it possible to have several threads writing in the same array but in staying at their place in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am writing a huge piece of code that do a sluggish operation but several times (almost 150 times)  and I am trying to make the code faster by using multithreading to parallelize several instances of the main operation. The result of each operation instance has to be stored in an array but the main goal is not to have all of the threads writing in the same part of the array.Problem: the code that perform the sluggish operation is extremely long (400 lines and multiple operations) so I have the solution to copy-paste these 400 lines 150 times and moddify some things in each of the instances of the code but I am already struggling because of the size of the whole code.

So in order to simplify the lecture and debugging of my code I am trying to do a loop with a generic version of the piece of code I try to multithread. Problem: with that method I cannot assign to each threat its place to write in the result array by hand. I try to use a shared variable between the threads that will be used as the index of their place in the array but I am encountering some errors and I am not sure to do the right thing to upgrade my code.
I made an extremely basic code that take the architecture (if i can call it like this) of my project:

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};


fn main(){
    let shared_array = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0;10]));//i create an array that can be shared between the threads
    let shared_array_copy = shared_array.clone();
    let shared_j = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0 as usize));//i create a variable that will be used as an index
    let shared_j_copy = shared_array.clone();
        let mut j = shared_j_copy.lock().unwrap();//i get the index variable to increment it each turn.
    for i in 1..10{//i do a loop to simplify the lecture of my code (instead of copying my 300 lines long piece of code several times)
        thread::spawn(move || {//in the thread i will put my piece of code that do the long operation
            let mut tab = shared_array_copy.lock().unwrap();
            let mut j = shared_j_copy.lock().unwrap();
            
            println!("I write in tab[{:?}]",j);
            tab[j]=j;// I try to use the j variable as an index to write in the good place
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            });
            
            j+=1;
    }
        
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10000));
        let mut tab = shared_array_copy.lock().unwrap();
        println!("tab= {:?}",tab);  //i print the result tab to verify that all went right
}
```

and the compiller return this error to me:

```
testweb 10:29:14 dim. janv. 08  $ rustc testmulti.rs
```

error[E0277]: the type `[{integer}]` cannot be indexed by `MutexGuard<'_, [{integer}; 10]>`
--> testmulti.rs:19:8
|
19 |             tab[j]=j;
|                 ^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
|
= help: the trait `SliceIndex<[{integer}]>` is not implemented for `MutexGuard<'_, [{integer}; 10]>`
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Index<MutexGuard<'_, [{integer}; 10]>>` for `[{integer}]`

error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `MutexGuard<'_, [{integer}; 10]>`
--> testmulti.rs:23:7
|
23 |             j+=1;
|             -^^^
|             |
|             cannot use `+=` on type `MutexGuard<'_, [{integer}; 10]>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0368.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.

In this example I use shared_j as the index that will increment each turn of the loop to ensure that the thread of the following turn of the loop will write his result in the following place in the array but it dont work and i dont know if it could work.

Comment: It definitely can work, but you're holding the lock across the `sleep`. Much of this boilerplate can probably be replaced by using a crate designed for this usecase like [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon)

Comment: Also "it dont work" is not an adequate description of your errors, if it doesn't compile you should [edit] your question and add the full output of the compiler, if it compiles but you get an output different from the one you expected you should state expected and actual behaviour or in short, provide a complete [mre].